# Upgrade processes between FreeBSD/Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, freebsd

Are there significant differences between FreeBSD and Ubuntu Linux when it comes to upgrading? FreeBSD appears to offers a more reliable path for upgrades with "freebsd-update" though I think "apt-get update --system" is the equivalent for Ubuntu.

I'll like to know which one is less likely to produce SNAFUs when undertaking minor/major updates.

Answer (score 2):

*freebsd-update* only updates the base system. As per [the FreeBSD handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/updating-freebsdupdate.html#AEN30931) you should also update all your ports after upgrading between releases with:

```
portupgrade -af
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu you use "*apt-get update*" to update the list of available packages, "*apt-get upgrade*" or "*apt-get dist-upgrade*" to get package updates (the names are historically, "dist-upgrade" will add or remove packages if that's needed to fulfil dependencies while "update" would rather not install the updates in this case) and "*do-release-upgrade*" to upgrade to a new release.

I don't use FreeBSD, Ubuntu is usually quite reliable at updates if you stick with the software from the official repositories. It doesn't have a way to roll back updates.